# Replace /n with real utf-8 with return code

Tags: java

So I just finish to code a little project and I can't figure out a way to pass this problem. Basically I need to replace /n with a return and I can't find a way of doing it.. Here's a bit of my code:

```
s.replaceAll("/n", ?);
```

The ? is the problem.. 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: what do you really mean? is not clear to me

Comment: I want to know what would replace /n because it is not working..

Comment: What do you think `/n` should represent? Did you perhaps mean `\n`?

Comment: what is not working? what do you want to replace with "/n" or you are asking what you can replace with "/n" or "\n"?

Comment: Please be more specific than “it is not working.”  What do you expect to see?  And what is “a return”?  Are you referring to the underlying platform’s newline sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
System.lineSeparator()
```

or (older java vs.)

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s = s.replaceAll("/n", "\n");
```